# Suggestions for problem-solving books

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I've recently been solving some of the questions in the PROMYS entrance test. I like how the last few problems seem puzzle-like (I mean that you wouldn't expect to find them on a maths exam), but they're still challenging (to me). They don't feel 'technical', unlike most olympiad problems. Does anyone have any suggestions as for where I can find other such problems?

Comment: What are "such problems" exactly? Can you give an example?

Comment: Let P0 be an equilateral triangle of area 10. Each side of P0 is trisected, and the corners are snipped off, creating a new polygon (in fact, a hexagon) P1. What is the area of P1? Now repeat the process to P1 – i.e. trisect each side and snip off the corners – to obtain a new polygon P2. What is the area of P2? Now repeat this process infinitely often to create an object P∞. What is the area of P∞?
note: please do not comment on the solution since the application form is still open

Comment: One might not require much mathematical knowledge to solve that problem, but it's still not 'easy'